# Access control of the multi variables in switch condition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can get the count of the if the elements are true condition for all the 5 questions in my form:

```
var count1 = 0, 
    a1 = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop1]').val(),
    a2 = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop2]').val(),
    a3 = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop3]').val(),
    a4 = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop4]').val(),
    a5 = $('form[name="myForm"]').find('select[name=drop5]').val();
              
for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
    switch(a[i])
             {
            case "2":
                alert("right");
                count++;
            break;
            case "1":
                alert("wrong");
            
            break;
            case "3":
                alert("wrong");
        
            break;
            case "4":
                alert("wrong");
            
            break;
            default:
                alert("wrong");
        }
             
}
```

Please give to some help to me in getting the score when all the options are set to true (2 option).

Answer (score 1):

```
var trueAnswers = 0;
$('form[name="myForm"] select[name^=drop]').each(function() {
  if (!!$(this).val()) trueAnswers++;
});

if (2 === trueAnswers) {
    alert('right');
}
```

or  just use `filter()`

```
var trueAnswers = $('form[name="myForm"] select[name^=drop]').filter(function() {
   return (!!$(this).val()) 
});

if (trueAnswers.length === 2) {
   alert('right');
}
```